# How can I adjust the span between under bar and formula

Tags: formatting

#### *Mathematica*:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### LaTeX:

$\alpha =\underset{\square }{\overset{\square }{\lim  \sup  \sqrt[n]{\left|a_n\right|}}}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the question contains no information about the context, I assume you only want to typeset the expression in a `TraditionalForm` cell.

Then just highlight the placeholder under the formula and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>$\uparrow$</kbd> two or three times, according to your taste. Each key press will nudge the placeholder (or superscript) up toward the formula.

You may want to look up [`AdjustmentBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AdjustmentBox.html) for more information.

Comment: ha, yes, thanks. I seldom use that, nearly forgot it when need that!